# macro to reference cell on excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Its a very basic question i am very new to this.Please help
I need to create  a lable format for sku and number of quantity and then print them out
EG:
Sheet 1(Purchase order sheet) has two cloumn

```
Sku          Qty

Bracelets-BB003   6

Bracelets-BB004   8

Bracelets-BB029   5
```

I have around more than 500 rows.

I need the data in the below format

```
Bracelets-BB003                   
      6                                




Bracelets-BB004      
      8

Bracelets-BB004
```

So that i can print and cut them as individual labels

Details: sheet 1 name :Purchase Order

output format:

```
 sku name

 quantity
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do it:

```
Sub LabelPrint()

   Dim exWSInput as Excel.Worksheet, exWSOutput as Excel.Worksheet
   Dim i as Long
   Dim vItem as Variant

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Set exWSInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input values sheetname") ' Change sheetname
   Set exWSOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output values sheetname") ' Change sheetname

   With exWSInput

      ' Loop through rows
      For i = 1 to 500 ' change numbers accordingly
           vItem = Split(.Cells(i,2), Chr(32)) ' Change "2" to appropriate column

           ' insert split values into output (destination) sheet
           exWSOutput.Cells(i, 2) = vItem(0) ' Change "2" to appropriate column
           exWSOutput.Cells(i, 3) = CLng(vItem(1)) ' Change "3" to appropriate column
      Next i
   End With

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Notice that you have to adjust the references and row numbers in the loop to make it work, so please read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub LabelPrint()

Dim skuNumberSht As Worksheet, labelsSht As Worksheet
Dim iniRow As Long, lastRow As Long

Set skuNumberSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SkuNumber") ' <== change "input" sheet name as per your needs
Set labelsSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Labels") ' <== change "output" sheet name as per your needs

With skuNumberSht.Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<== change "Qty" column index as per your needs
    iniRow = .Rows(1).Row
    lastRow = .Areas(.Cells.Count).Row
End With

With labelsSht.Cells(iniRow, 1).Resize(2)
    .Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array("=" & skuNumberSht.Name & "!RC", "=" & skuNumberSht.Name & "!R[-1]C[+1]"))
    .Copy .Resize(lastRow - iniRow + 2)
End With

End Sub
```

it works for whatever rows you have in "input" sheets as long as they're "paired" (a row with data in two columns and a blank row)

you just have to change sheets names and column index with "Qty" as per your needs.